# Open Graph Protocol Image Too Small Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-images, open-graph

I notice the default code for the image open graph protocol generates the smallest image available.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getImage($block->getProduct(), 'product_base_image')->getImageUrl()) ?>" />
```

How do I get the image that's shown on the product page (which is actually over 1000px)?

I am trying to upload products to a Facebook catalogue via pixel (it uses Open Graph data). And I can only presume this is the reason why it's not working correctly.

Comment: did u try to add these parameters,                                                                           <meta property="og:image:width" content="200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200" />

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a custom theme, you can override **Magento_Catalog::product/view/opengraph/general.phtml** by the following steps:

1. Create the a template file like bellow struct:

> app/design/frontend/YourTheme/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/opengraph/general.phtml

2. Change this:

`<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getImage($block->getProduct(), 'product_base_image')->getImageUrl()); ?>" />`

to

`<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getImage($block->getProduct(), 'product_page_image_large')->getImageUrl()); ?>" />`

Now, your open graph protocol image will be changed to the large image. I tried this and it worked fine for me

Comment: Not working for me in 2.2.6 Lee. Gives me the exact same result as the original piece of code...

Comment: It works for me on 2.2.6. Before: https://imgur.com/a/qplfMpg After: 
 https://imgur.com/a/4WHidAi .  Please make sure you cleaned block_html cache and your custom theme is activating